# PHP, How would I load different content for a page depending on a url variable?

Tags: php, variables

For example:

if I just have cite.php, it would default to something

if it is cite.php?c=1, then it would load other content.

same as cite.php?c=2 ....etc

I did it before using a switch,case statement but I forgot how to do it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$f = $_GET["c"];

switch($f){
  case 1:
    /* content here*/
  break;

  case 2:
  /* content here*/
  break;
}
```

Comment: What happens if $f is null? :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code:

```
        $c = isset($_GET['c'])?$_GET['c'] : ''; 
    switch ($c) {

    case 1:
        /* Do something related to 1 */
        break;
    case 2:
        /* Do something related to 2 */
        break;
    default:
      /* Do something related to default */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the &_GET variable:

```
<?php echo $_GET["c"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll use `$_GET[]`

```
if isset($_GET['c']) {
    /* write code to show specific info *?
} else {
    /* show other info here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this much simpler with if statements

place this code in the header page

```
<?php 

$page = $_GET['c'];

if(!isset($page)) {
    header('location:cite.php?c=1');
    exit;
}

?>
```

then use this to load display different element on the page(place between `<body></body>` tags)

```
<? if ($page == "1") {?>

<h2>page 1</h2>

<? } else if ($page == "2") { ?>
<h2>page 2</h2>


<? } ?>
```

and the links will look like this

```
<a herf="cite.php?c=1">Link 1</a> <a herf="cite.php?c=2">Link 2</a>
```